# Value not show in datagridview as inputed in textbox

Tags: c#, datagridview

Can you help me, I want to input "0.20" as my rate but it keeps showing "0.00", btw my database is MS SQL. Here is my code

```
string tempDiscRate = disRateTxt.Text.Trim();                

string addquery = "INSERT INTO PROD_DISCOUNT (PROD_DISC_RATE) VALUES 
             ('" + Convert.ToDouble(tempDiscRate) + "')";
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(addquery, conn);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

     //ON FORM_LOAD
dscDgv.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
dscDgv.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
```

Comment: `(0.20).ToString("N2")` works fine. What is the value that you try to show _exactly_?

Comment: I want to show the value "0.20" as I insert it in my database and i want it to appears as it is

Comment: What is the datatype of the column?

Comment: Btw, you code won't _even_ compile. Please show short but complete program demonstrating your problem..

Comment: @TaW it's a decimal type